# Multi databases in django project, dublicate the database

Tags: python, django

**Multi databases in django project, dublicate the database**

While posting the form of models, it must be stored in two databases at a time. like dublicate the database.

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'auth_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'auth_db.db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'primary': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'primary.db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'app_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app_db.db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'app2_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app2_db.db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['routers.AuthRouter', 'routers.PrimaryReplicaRouter']
```

**Routers file in project**

read, write in first routers is working(auth_db), if create same in other it is not working.

routers.py

```
import random
class AuthRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth and contenttypes applications.
    """
    route_app_labels = {'auth', 'contenttypes'}
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth and contenttypes models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'auth_db'
        return None
    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth and contenttypes models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'auth_db'
        return None
    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth or contenttypes apps is
        involved.
        """
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
           return True
        return None
    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth and contenttypes apps only appear in the
        'auth_db' database.
        """
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'auth_db'
        return None
class PrimaryReplicaRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Reads go to a randomly-chosen replica.
        """
        return random.choice(['app_db', 'app2_db'])
    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Writes always go to primary.
        """
        return 'primary'
    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
        in the primary/replica pool.
        """
        db_set = {'primary','app_db', 'app2_db'}
        if obj1._state.db in db_set and obj2._state.db in db_set:
            return True
        return None
    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        All non-auth models end up in this pool.
        """
        return True
```

**I am geting the data from any databases by using method**

i want to post in two databases, even with two views also no problem(two different pages) with same model,serializer.

views.py

```
class testview(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = testmodel.objects.all().using('auth_db')
    serializer_class = testserializer

class testview2(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = testmodel.objects.all().using('app_db')
    serializer_class = testserializer
```

Comment: Mohammad why does it need to duplicate database, this will make your *working with data* more complex. If you want to duplicate your data then change your model, if any help, then messge me, I hope I can solve your problem.

Comment: Han Ji, thank you for reply, as per client requirement i want to store this full project data in two databases like sql and nosql, so that all can manage in sql databases and nosql for to store some of the fields to store and manage by admin only. if in further any data loss or any problem then we can use this nosql. present i want searching about duplicate in two databases. like post in two databases at a time.